# Ошибка в PL/SQL IF ELSE условие

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

При написании такого простого кода возникает следующая ошибка

```
1.a = null
2.b = 20.08.2022 18:36:19
3.c = 12.08.2022 17:25:03

IF a = 1 
OR (b IS NOT NULL AND c IS NOT NULL AND TRUNC(b) = TRUNC(c)) 
OR (b IS NOT NULL and c IS NULL AND TRUNC(b) = TRUNC(#APPLICATION.TIME_STAMP#))
   THEN RESULT:= 1;
    ELSE RESULT:= 0;
    END IF;
```

Код выдаёт следующую ошибку:

"ORA-06550: line 5, column 67:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to '='
ORA-06550: line 5, column 1:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
"

Подскажите как можно решить проблему?

Comment: что у вас такое RESULT?

Comment: У вас совсем [другая ошибка](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=6b6c2e7ea5dee0ef217398320ef29a4e). Как вы получили указанную в вопросе?